# UITableView cell disappears when returning from detail screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I have a tableview with a custom cell that display a series of UIViews in a stackview. Pretty simple layout. I then have another viewcontroller that I am using as a detail page for any of the selected items in the tableview. When you tap on the tableview cell it opens the detail view by pushing it onto the navigation controller stack. When you press back the selected cell of the tableview is now visibly gone. However you can still tap in the area it was at and it will open the detail page again. It's like the opacity got turn down to 0 or something.

I have the selection style set to none in the IB as well.

Here's the main viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class PaletteTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cp1 = ColorPalette(colorsInPalette: [ColorView(color: UIColor.red, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.purple, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.gray, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.green, frame: CGRect.zero)])

    let cp2 = ColorPalette(colorsInPalette: [ColorView(color: UIColor.black, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.blue, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.brown, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.red, frame: CGRect.zero),
                                             ColorView(color: UIColor.yellow, frame: CGRect.zero)])

    // This has to be a lazy var since you can't reference self (or other properties) during initialization
    lazy var colorPalettes : [ColorPalette] = [cp1, cp2]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavBar()
        setupTabBar()

    }

    func setupNavBar() {
        // Set the nav bar to have large titles. This is on a per instance basis
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }

    func setupTabBar() {
        tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colorPalettes.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "paletteCell", for: indexPath) as! PaletteTableViewCell

        // Get the current color palette
        let currentPalete = colorPalettes[indexPath.row]

        // From the current palette loop through all the color views and add them to the cell's color stack view
        for colorView in currentPalete.colors! {
            cell.colorStackView.addArrangedSubview(colorView)
        }

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Get the detailviewcontroller from this current storyboard
        if let detailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailPaletteViewController") as? DetailPaletteViewController {
            // Get the currently selected color palette and set that as the main color palette for the detail view
            detailViewController.colorPalette = colorPalettes[indexPath.row]

            // Push the detail view controller onto the nav bar view stack
            navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}

class PaletteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var colorStackView: UIStackView!
}
```

Here's the detail viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class DetailPaletteViewController: UIViewController {

    var colorPalette : ColorPalette!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorStackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // For each color view in the current color palette, add it to the stack view for it to manage each color view equally
        if let colors = colorPalette.colors {
            for colorView in colors {
                colorStackView.addArrangedSubview(colorView)
            }
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I'm not sure why it would happen.

Comment: Does reloading the tableview fix the issue?
Have you tried to reload the tableview when you return to main screen from detail viewcontroller.

Comment: Do you have also xib for your cell ?

Comment: Not sure if it is related, but it seems that you keep adding color views to your cells stackview. You should probably remove all sub views of the stackview before adding the colorviews.

Comment: @mihatel Yes it's designed in the prototype cell in the IB. It displays correctly on the initial startup of the app but disappears when return from the detail view controller.

Comment: @Sune Ah okay I didn't realize that was needed. Could you walk me through why? It seems that if a cell was removed from view it's no longer in memory so I wouldn't be adding more views to an existing cell when scrolling back to it. And those views in current view would only run once. Is the issue when returning back to the viewcontroller from another? Wouldn't iOS remove the cells from memory when changing view controllers?

Comment: @MaxMcKinney: I can't see your nib registration code, you didn't paste it here or it is missing at all ? There should be something like this:                let nibProfile = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nibProfile, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

Comment: @mihatel I don't belive a nib is needed if I'm using the interface builder to build the cell. You can see I created a PaletteTableViewCell of type UITableViewCell that I've assigned to the prototype cell in the IB. This is then referenced in the cellForRowAt by using the identifier of the prototype cell I made earlier. Am I correct in assuming I don't need a nib registration code in this instance?

Comment: @MaxMcKinney: When a cell scrolls off view, it is reused as the cell scrolling into the view. This way you don't have to keep thousands of cells in memory for large lists. That means that you have to clear (or reset) everything when populating a cell, or your cells will look strange after they have been scrolled.

Comment: @MaxMcKinney: Is it possible to provide source so I can run it myself ?